# watch DNS queries while using OpenVPN.-

Tags: linux, dns, openvpn, iptables, docker

I want to monitor/sniff the DNS queries I make while I'm using a VPN connection with my OpenVPN client.
My initial motivation was to check if I'm leaking DNS queries; then using [this](http://www.dnsleaktest.com) page it seems I'm not leaking, but I still want to understand the pipeline of my network "dynamics".

I'm running the OpenVPN client in a Docker container, and I set these firewall rules right before establishing the vpn connection:

```
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tap0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT 

iptables -A OUTPUT -d ${docker_network} -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -d ${vpn_ip} -p tcp -m tcp --dport $port -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport $port -j ACCEPT
```

where: `vpn_ip` is the IP of the vpn server, `port` the UDP port for the vpn connection, and `docker_network` is the local network of the container (e.g. 172.17.0.2/16).
Everything below is executed inside the container.

I read everywhere that DNS queries are made to the DNS servers of the VPN provider, so I'd like to "see" that somehow.
So I made a ping:

```
ping -c1 hotmail.com
```

and it responds normally.
At this point the `/etc/resolv.conf` contains:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Next, I clean the `/etc/resolv.conf` to see if the query needs it, so I  repeat the ping command and I get:

```
ping: hotmail.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Also, if I try to use a browser on top of this container, it doesn't load any page as it usually would.

---

I also "sniffed" my packets while the `resolv.conf` was using `8.8.8.8` like so:

```
tcpdump -i tun0 -vv "host 8.8.8.8"
```

and I get lines like:

```
10.8.8.7.39209 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: [udp sum ok] 17379+ PTR? ...
```

I've also tried this with the interface `-i eth0` and I get complete silence.

Doing a filter-less sniff, I also checked that `eth0` only sees UDP packets, while `tun0` sees TCP **and** UDP packets.

Why do I need a valid `/etc/resolv.conf` if the DNS query is supposed to be sent over the vpn client?
The DNS queries are sent directly to 8.8.8.8 or through my vpn connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do I need a valid /etc/resolv.conf if the DNS query is supposed to be sent over the vpn client?

The `/etc/resolv.conf` is the configuration for the resolver libraries which DNS server should be used. Even if you are using a VPN you still need a DNS server. Only, the communication with the given DNS server should be done through the VPN then.

For example if you use 8.8.8.8 as the DNS server then you should see the DNS query passing through your VPN interface (tun0 in your case) - which you also see there according to your question:

```
tcpdump -i tun0 -vv "host 8.8.8.8"
10.8.8.7.39209 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: [udp sum ok] 17379+ PTR? ...
```

If you instead would use a DNS server in the local network (like 172.17.0.1) then the DNS query would not go through the VPN interface since the route to the local network is not set through the VPN interface (check `netstat -rn` or `ip route` for details). You would instead see the query pass through another interface (possibly `eth0`, depending on your exact setup). In this case you would have a DNS leak since the DNS query is bypassing the VPN.

Comment: nice! so given that in my local network I don't have any DNS server (to my knowledge), and according to my iptables rules above, it should be impossible for DNS queries to go anywhere except through `tun0` right?

Comment: Given that you have explicitly set a DNS in your resolv.conf which can only be reached through the VPN all applications which use this DNS server should have no DNS leaks. Note that there are applications which might use different DNS, like DNS over HTTPS configured in the web browser (which likely goes over the VPN too).